# Weird crashes "java.lang.ArithmeticException divide by zero"

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Recently I found out from Firebase Crashlytics that some HTC/Fortuneship 
 devices crashes with the next exception and I can't understand why

[image]

```
val formattedViews: String
   get() = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%,d %s", viewCount, Util.getString(R.string.views))
```

I don't get how such exception can happen in this code

Is there something wrong with those devices?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the JDK shipping with Android 7: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8167567

You are passing `Locale.getDefault()` to `format()`, which is the same as not specifying a locale at all. The only known workaround appears to be to use a known-good locale to do the formatting (e.g. `Locale.US`), but of course this means you won't get locale-specific thousands groupings for users outside the US.

Or you could change your format specification to not use groupings (i.e. `%d` without the comma).

Perhaps you could `catch` the exception and fall back to US formatting for users who would otherwise crash? That's what these guys did: https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/pull/5604/files

Comment: Thanks. I decided to catch exception and use US locale in such case